# Django Rest Framework Choices Field Serializer -- I'd like to get second element in a tuple

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

This is a model

```
class BookModel(models.Model):
    """The model to represent books."""

    class BookRating(models.IntegerChoices):
        AWFUL = 0, 'Awful'
        BAD = 1, 'Bad'
        NORMAL = 2, 'Normal'
        GOOD = 3, 'Good'
        GREAT = 4, 'Great'
        AWSOME = 5, 'Awesome'
     
    rating = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=BookRating.choices, null=True, blank=True)
```

And this is a serializer

```
Class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

     rating = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=BookModel.BookRating.choices, source='rating')

     class Meta:
         model = BookModel
         fields = '__all__'
```

How do I serialize it properly in my case? I saw the answer here were somone used a tuple of tuples and it worked with the logic I have, but idk how to do it when I use another class's choices for creating choices (sorry for tautology)

Comment: I can of course make a method for that and then use SerializerMethodField, but it seems unnecessary

Comment: `AWFUL = 0, (0, 'Awful')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's what i needed

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    rating = serializers.CharField(source='get_rating_display')

    class Meta:
        model = BookModel
        fields = '__all__'
```